# connecting ecw to its projection and grid data in an xml file

Tags: coordinate-system, xml, ecw, mapwindow

I'm new to mapping please go easy on me:)
I have a bunch of ecw files with 2 xml file one is a file ending with *.ecw.xml [image: *.ecw.xml]
and one with 
*.ecw.aux.xml[image: aux.xml]

I am trying to load the ecw files into mapwindow as a layer but get a message that it is an invalid data source.
I know I have to connect the projection and other data to the ecw file but just can't find out how. I have roamed the web but couldn't find any explanation. I might be searching the wrong key words due to my lack of knowledge. I also tried to load the ecw file in ecw header editor but it won't load there either.